# How to access non-localized description of Error?

Tags: swift, error-handling, localization

It seems that the `Error` type in Swift provides only one property, `localizedDescription`. My app will be running on machines set to other languages than English. I would like to write error reports (for my perusal, not the user’s) in English: I need the non-localized description of the error. How can I get it?

Comment: cast this error to `CustomStringConvertible` or `CustomDebugStringConvertible`

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this issue is create a string using the error's domain and code. Something like:

```
extension Error {
    var logString: String {
        return (self as NSError).code + ":" + (self as NSError).domain
    }
}
```